# discord.js does not respond to commands

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have done discord.js bot recently, but it does not respond to commands, like !greeting.
Here is a code of index.js

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const robot = new Client
({ intents: [ GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages ] });
const comms = require("./comms.js"); 
const fs = require('fs'); 
let config = require('./config.json'); 
let prefix = config.prefix;
let token = config.token; 

robot.on("ready", function() {
  console.log(robot.user.username + " пробудився, і готовий ділитися мудрістю...");
});


robot.on('message', (msg) => { 
  if (msg.author.username != robot.user.username && msg.author.discriminator != robot.user.discriminator) {
    var comm = msg.content.trim() + " ";
    var comm_name = comm.slice(0, comm.indexOf(" "));
    var messArr = comm.split(" ");
    for (comm_count in comms.comms) {
      var comm2 = prefix + comms.comms[comm_count].name;
      if (comm2 == comm_name) {
        comms.comms[comm_count].out(robot, msg, messArr);
      }
    }
  }
});

robot.login(token);
```

And here is comms.js

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
let config = require('./config.json');
let prefix = config.prefix;

function test(robot, mess, args) {
  mess.channel.send('Test!')
}
function greeting(robot, mess, args) {
  mess.reply("Вітаю тебе! Почуй мою мудрість, і ставатимеш як я...")
}

var comms_list = [
  {
  name: "test",
  out: test,
  about: "Тестова команда"
  }];

    comms_list.push({
    name: "greeting",
    out: greeting,
    about: "Команда для вітання"
  });

module.exports.comms = comms_list;
```

What I should to do??? I with my friend sit on it for three days.
Looking forward to hearing from you!

Comment: The `message` event is deprecated. Instead of `robot.on('message')`, use `robot.on('messageCreate')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the `MessageContent` intent as well in your client. This flag is required if you want to read the contents of a message as well. Also you are using a deprecated event, you should use `messageCreate` instead:

```js
robot.on('messageCreate', (msg) => {
```

And while you're at it, you are trying to read the author / user object that's within the message collection. In order to read this, you also have to enable two other intents:

```js
GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences
```

So, the final client initialization should look like this:

```js
const robot = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences
    ]
});
```

Also make sure to enable the intents on the [Discord Developer Console](https://discord.com/developers) as well otherwise you won't be able to receive the events.